# Ionic 4 ion-chip in text input like Discord tags

Tags: angular, ionic4, discord

How do I put `ion-chip` in a `ion-input`?

I wanted to make a chat bar like Discord with `@everyone` or `#here`. But when I try to put html in the input, I can’t write in anymore.

here is my code:

```
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Enter a message">
  <ion-chip color="medium" mode="ios">
    <ion-label>@everyone</ion-label>
  </ion-chip>
  hello everyone
</ion-input>
```

In addition, I wanted to include the code syntax highlighting: I tried with `ngx-highlightjs` and `ion-prism` but it failed.

Like this:
[image]

Does someone have an idea how to do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the code you're using.

Comment: Hope it is not late or can help someone else 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-tags-input